# How to stop my exes from being treated like a virus?

Tags: python, exe, signing

I noticed any exe application I make are treated like viruses upon download. This is terrible, how do I make them legitimate? I read something about self-signing, but I still don't get it. What is the process of self signing and how do I do it? If it helps I am using pygame, python, on pycharm, with pyinstaller, on Windows 10.

Comment: The problem is with the anti-virus software falsely recognising part of `pyinstaller` as a malware. I actually opened a [github issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5479) on this exact problem a few days ago. The solution, other then for self-signing, is to use "one version older" than the current release of `pyinstaller` (at the moment 4.1) that the anti-virus software has learned (by users input) is not a malware

Comment: So you're saying if I make the exe with an outdated version of pyinstaller, it won't be recognized as malware? That's interesting! Do you know how I can do that via pip?

Comment: **treated like viruses upon download** are they marked by an antivirus, or just windows gives you a warning when your try to execute them? The later is standard behavior.

Comment: Yes, or make sure your anti-virus definition is most up-to-date. It's a cat-vs-a-mouse thing

Comment: @mouse123 `pip install -U pyinstaller==4.1` If that does not work (I'm not sure if `-U` can downgrade), first do `pip uninstall pyinstaller`

Comment: Yes it's windows giving out the warning

Comment: This isn't a good SO question because it isn't amenable to a canonically correct answer that's going to _stay_ correct over time; antivirus databases are constantly changing, and if there were a reliable way to avoid detection, people who _were_ writing malware would use it, so the AV would be updated so it no longer worked. If this is a Windows Defender problem, you should be reporting it to Microsoft instead of asking us here; likewise for any other AV vendor.

Comment: It's not a serious problem or anything, I was wondering how indie game developers get their games authenticated. Websites like Gamejolt have safe exes. Windows is functioning as it should. Is SO isn't a good place, can you recommend a better place?

Comment: Different AV and OS vendors do things differently. For Apple, for example, they consider something unknown until it's been widely enough seen in nonmalicious contexts (building an executable with their tools signs it, but that signature doesn't actually infer any trust).

Comment: Microsoft _does_ support a code-signing ecosystem, but if just having a any signature was enough to be marked eternally trusted, all your malware vendors would do that, so it would be worthless. In the real world, one ends up with a mix of static and dynamic analysis, and the details of how vendors do those things are closely held, since if they got out it would make evasion easier.

Comment: ...paying money to get into a developer program is often one part of the process (to stop bad actors from creating new identities and getting new signing keys after they were caught signing malware with old ones), to make there be a financial penalty for throwing away one identity and getting a new one. Hence, Microsoft having things like https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/store/register/, and Apple likewise.

Comment: ...but as was said before, it's a cat-and-mouse game; the ground is constantly changing as attackers and defenders try to find new ways to outwit each other.

Comment: So then the main take would be that there's no easy way for me to get authenticated, right?

Answer (score 0):

You cant, or it is hard, to fix that your program treats as virus at antiviruses because av's use euristhic analysis and machine learning so they could make your program false positive. You have to go to av's forums and ask why your app is false positive.